# Data Mining, Statistics, Collective Intelligence and AI Algorithms Books and Programming Resources

Tags: artificial-intelligence, data-mining, collective-intelligence

In my effort to continuously improve myself, I decided to learn about Data Mining, Statistics, Collective Intelligence and AI Algorithms, and well, that sort of stuff.

What are the **free** ebooks, and web resources ( tutorials, code) etc that I can use on?

Comment: I long for the days when calling someone a ***Data Miner*** was an *appropriate* insult.

Answer (score 2):

You may have a look at http://cci.mit.edu/.

Answer (score 2):

This one is a good primer: http://www.inference.phy.cam.ac.uk/itprnn/book.html

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to find pdf versions of:

- Programming Collective Intelligence (Toby Segaran)
- Visualizing Data (Ben Fry)

Highly recommended.

Answer (score 1):

Stanford has two data mining courses on YouTube. search "machine learning" and "data mining"

MIT has a free online data mining course at. Google "MIT OCW"

also: Google "kdnuggets data mining course"

and: http://www.autonlab.org/tutorials/

Opensource Software:

RapidMiner
R with Rattle

Answer (score 1):

[The Elements of Statistical Learning: Data Mining, Inference, and Prediction.](http://www-stat.stanford.edu/~tibs/ElemStatLearn/)